# Upload xml file to server

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, nsurlsession

I am trying to upload a file like this:

```
- (NSString *)uploadWithTarget:(NSString *)url andFileData:(NSData *)file andMD5Checksum:(NSString *)checksum andFileName:(NSString *)name
{
uploadFinished = false;
NSString *response = @"";

NSURLSessionConfiguration *defaultConfigObject = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSURLSession *defaultSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration: defaultConfigObject delegate: self delegateQueue: [NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];

NSURL * urll = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
NSMutableURLRequest * urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:urll];
[urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[urlRequest addValue:checksum forHTTPHeaderField:@"Md5Hash"];
[urlRequest addValue:@"Keep-Alive" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Connection"];


NSString *boundary = @"*****";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
[urlRequest addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

/*
 now lets create the body of the post
 */
NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n", name] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/xml\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:file]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
// setting the body of the post to the reqeust
[urlRequest setHTTPBody:body];


NSURLSessionDataTask * dataTask = [defaultSession dataTaskWithRequest:urlRequest];
//[dataTask resume];

NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask = [defaultSession
                                      uploadTaskWithRequest:urlRequest
                                      fromData:file
                                      completionHandler:^(NSData *data,
                                                          NSURLResponse *response,
                                                          NSError *error)
{
    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResp = (NSHTTPURLResponse*) response;

    if (!error && httpResp.statusCode == 200) {
        NSLog(@"Request body %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[urlRequest HTTPBody] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);

    } else {

    }
}];


[uploadTask resume];

return response;
}
```

But my Server always responds File not Found! Is that not correct code?!

Comment: Seek support from the server admin.

Comment: But with my Code is everything fine?!

Comment: Don't know - didn't look.  If you cannot get support from the server admin (cos he doesn't know you, for example) then you're going to need to capture the HTTP requests and responses using a web debugging proxy like this: http://www.charlesproxy.com/ or like this: http://fiddler2.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (void) uploadLog :(NSString *) filePath
{
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
NSString *urlString =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.yoursite.com/accept.php"];
// to use please use your real website link.
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *boundary = @"_187934598797439873422234";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
[request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:@"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5) AppleWebKit/536.26.14 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0.1 Safari/536.26.14" forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];
[request setValue:@"http://google.com" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Origin"];

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Length %d\r\n\r\n", [data length] ] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"picture\"; filename=\"%@.png\"\r\n", @"newfile"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:data]];

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


[request setHTTPBody:body];
[request addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [body length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];


NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@", returnString);
}
```

And here is the php part that works for me.

```
<?php
    $target_path = "./uploads/";  

    $target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['picture']['name']);  

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['picture']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {  
    echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['picture']['name'])." has been uploaded";  
    } else{  
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";  
    } 
 ?>
```

Comment: happy to help enjoy happy coding...+1 for me